# Does Require.JS prevent visitors from viewing/copying External Scripts?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I recently got into RequireJS and am integrating it into my backbone applications. 
I noticed when looking at the source code that all individual javascripts are replaced by the bootstrap file, the line that reads:

```
<script data-main="js/main" src="js/require.js"></script>
```

And this line prevents me from viewing the attached files.
Does this mean that users are unable to hack their way into my external source code files if I load all scripts through the bootstrap file?

I am mostly concerned because I use a restful api route in my Backbone collections, and want to keep user data safe.

Thanks.

Comment: If it's Javascript, it's viewable in the user's browser.

Comment: You cannot prevent anyone from viewing JS code that is to be executed in their browser. If you have troubles to see it, check your devtools' network tab.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it doesn't mean that. It just means that scripts are loaded dynamically. Anybody can still download your JS files or look at them with any web debugging tool

Comment: To add to this, the general rule is that if a user is ever executing any of your javascript, they can see it.

Comment: Yes I thought it was an extra security feature from require.js, but as a module loader and source code minification with the included r.js it should do what I need. Thanks.